# Python - cx_Oracle - returns ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am tyring to connect to an oracle database using python cx_Oracle module.
When i try to execute a particular query, i get 'ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month'

Query:

```
select  case when to_date (STOP_DATE, 'dd-mon-yy')='01-JAN-01' then '000000' else  to_char(to_date(STOP_DATE,'dd-mon-yy'),'mmddyy') end STOP_DATE
                        from table1 where SYS_1= 1234 and rownum < 11
```

The same query works fine in sqlDeveloper.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Python code:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = None
try:
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host", "port", service_name="serviceName")
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=dsn_tns)
    c = connection.cursor()
    sqlStatement = r'''
                            select  case when to_date (STOP_DATE, 'dd-mon-yy')='01-JAN-01' then '000000' else  to_char(to_date(STOP_DATE,'dd-mon-yy'),'mmddyy') end STOP_DATE
                            from table1 where SYS_1= 1234 and rownum < 11

    '''
    c.execute(sqlStatement)
    resultSet = c.fetchall()
    if not len(resultSet) == 0:
            print("query successful!!!!!!!!!!")
            for row in resultSet:
                for items in row:
                   if items == None:
                      items = ""
                print (items)

    if connection:
        print('all executed')
        connection.close()

except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if connection:
           connection.close()
```

Comment: I presume STOP_DATE is a character column? Is there a reason you are storing STOP_DATE as a character column and not a date? That would eliminate the issues you are experiencing! You might want to consider fetching just a single row (the same one in both cases) to make sure you're not simply running into a data issue!

Comment: hi @AnthonyTuininga, STOP_DATE  is a date column but it is in a different format. (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS)

Comment: If STOP_DATE is a date column, then you should do this instead: stop_date = to_date('01-JAN-01', 'dd-MON-YY')